# Header not redirecting if __DIR__ is used

Tags: php

```
header ('Location:'.__DIR__.'/view/prijava_view.php'
```

If I use above header in index.php file it just shows a blank page with "localhost" URL. It works if I use include instead of header though.

Is this an issue with *DIR* magic constant? It seems you can't use it in headers, or do I have a problem with my code?

Comment: Is `__DIR__` not a local path?

Comment: I am using version 5.4.12, nothing in the error log

Comment: `__DIR__` contains the *file system path* to the current file, not the URL path.

Comment: Have you tried outputting the header you are sending, to see what it looks like after you concatenate `__DIR__`?

Comment: _DIR_ is a local path ony my computer "C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www/"

Comment: With a bit of luck (probably with internetexplorer 4 or 5) this perhaps could even work if you are surfing on the same computer as the website is served from :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`__DIR__` is a file-system path. It has NOTHING to do with the URLs that client browsers will see. If your site's files are physically stored at

```
/home/sites/example.com/html/view/projava_view.php
```

and the code inside this php script looks at **DIR**, you'll get

```
/home/sites/example.com/html/view/
```

if you pass that out via a header() for redirect, you'll be redirecting to a file-system path

```
header("Location: http://example.com/home/site/example.com/html/view/.....");
```

which is NOT reachable by external users. That path is NOT inside your document root, and the browser will actually be requesting the full path, which the server will then tack on the document root AGAIN, so the full end-request would actually be

```
/home/sites/example.com/html/view/home/sites/example.com/html/view/projava_view.php
```

In general, the `__DIR__` magic constant is utterly useless when trying to build URL-space paths, because it's not intended for use in URLs.

Comment: So I can't use it with headers only includes? What should I use in headers then, to avoid relative path problems

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` might be of use, to figure out which bits of the `__DIR__` path are "inside" and "outside" of the doc root.

Answer (score 1):

```
function redirect_by_path($path)
{
    $redirect = substr(strtr(realpath($path), '\\', '/'), strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));
    header("location: $redirect");
    exit;
}
```

Usage:

```
redirect_by_path(__DIR__ . '/../../login.php');
```

```
if (!is_logged_in())
{
    redirect_by_path(__DIR__ . '/../../login.php');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

`__DIR__` magic constant works on php 5.3+ . If your host php version doesn't support it you should use `dirname(__FILE__)` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/` and then add the path to your login page. It doesn't matter where you are.

Ex.: The user is in `website/admin/user/settings/config.php`.

Instead of using `header("Location: ../../../login.php");`,

you can use `header("Location: /login.php");`